# retry logic blocks the main consumer while its waiting for the retry in spring

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am referring:

> https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-implement-retry-logic-with-spring-kafka-710b51501ce2

And it says that if we use below:

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate), 3));
```

It will block the main consumer while its waiting for the retry. ([https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-implement-retry-logic-with-spring-kafka-710b51501ce2#:~:text=Also%20it%20blocks%20the%20main%20consumer%20while%20its%20waiting%20for%20the%20retry](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-implement-retry-logic-with-spring-kafka-710b51501ce2#:%7E:text=Also%20it%20blocks%20the%20main%20consumer%20while%20its%20waiting%20for%20the%20retry))

So, my question is do we really need retry on main topic or can we move the failed messages to a retry topic and then process messages there so that our main topic is non-blocking.

Can we achieve non-blocking retry using STCH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-blocking retries were recently added to the new 2.7 release.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic

> Achieving non-blocking retry / dlt functionality with Kafka usually requires setting up extra topics and creating and configuring the corresponding listeners. Since 2.7 Spring for Apache Kafka offers support for that via the `@RetryableTopic` annotation and RetryTopicConfiguration class to simplify that bootstrapping.

> If message processing fails, the message is forwarded to a retry topic with a back off timestamp. The retry topic consumer then checks the timestamp and if it’s not due it pauses the consumption for that topic’s partition. When it is due the partition consumption is resumed, and the message is consumed again. If the message processing fails again the message will be forwarded to the next retry topic, and the pattern is repeated until a successful processing occurs, or the attempts are exhausted, and the message is sent to the Dead Letter Topic (if configured).

Comment: one thing to note here we loose ordering of records functionality while using non-blocking retires. That is a significant trade off if you work on a usecase that requires messages to be ordered within partition.